# display: inline along with float: left

Tags: html, css

I am looking at some old CSS code from 2008 and saw the following CSS for a menu/navigation:

```
#menu li {
    display: inline;
}



#menu a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 18px 30px 0 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background: url(images/img03.jpg) no-repeat right top;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='menu'>
            <ul id='main'>
                <li class='current_page_item'><a href='#'>Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Products</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id='feed'>
                <li><a href='#'>Entries</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Comments RSS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/wrsdh7yj/1/

I don't understand the purpose of first setting the list item `inline` then making the anchor tags `block` and floating them left.

An explanation would help.

**Note** I put those background colors there to see what is going on.

Comment: the `display:block` was clearly a miss.

Comment: There's nothing to answer on this question.

Comment: Be careful you aren't giving credit to someone for code they wrote just cause it's on some web site. There's a lot of awful, awful code out there.

Answer (score 0):

The `display: inline` prevents the staircase effect/bug in IE7

Picture without `display: inline` in IE7 emulation

[image]

Comment: It is not only that. At that time you could make list items only `inline` or `block`. If he did blocks with floats, than he would have to add clearing as last list element, which developers avoided inside lists. 10 years ago it was not about the choice, but what you have to do (and also to test in IE6).